# How to compress and decompress a string with LZO?

Tags: c, lzo

Trying to figure out what the proper way to plug in my data is. Any help? Doing it in the way seen here results in integer without a cast. I've tried this a few ways but never quite got the hand of it.

```
lzo_bytep SERV_DATA_SEND = "702D31FA78809907133F1256459ABFECA9769AEAB65F3F125658";

in_len = IN_LEN;
lzo_memset(in,SERV_DATA_SEND,strlen(SERV_DATA_SEND));
printf("memset: %s\n\n", in);
```

Comment: Do you mean `lzo_memcpy` instead of `lzo_memset`?

Comment: lzo_memcpy doesn't seem to do the trick unless I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prepare the data in a buffer, you should use `lzo_memcpy(in, SERV_DATA_SEND, strlen(SERV_DATA_SEND))`, which accepts chars in its second parameter.

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn lzo_memcpy(
    dst: *mut c_void, 
    src: *const c_void, 
    len: lzo_uint
) -> *mut c_void
```

In `lzo_memset()`, the second parameter accepts an integer.

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn lzo_memset(
    buf: *mut c_void, 
    c: c_int, 
    len: lzo_uint
) -> *mut c_void
```

For example, if you want to clear the buffer, you can use the code below. It will set all the blocks to zero.

```
lzo_memset(in,0,in_len);
```

Check out the overlap.c and simple.c example in http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/#download

Comment: So I should use it like lzo_memcpy(in, SERV_DATA_SEND, in_len); ? I get a segfault from that.